# Trapezoid proof using scalar product

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

In the trapezium shown, $BE:BC= \frac{1}{3}$. Show that $3 \mathbf {AC} \cdot \mathbf {DE} = 2(4m^2-n^2)$, where $\mathbf {|AB|} = m$, $\mathbf {|DC|}=2|\mathbf {AB}|$ and $\mathbf {|DA|}=n$.

I tried using the geometric definition of scalar product to solve that. The required lengths of the two vectors may be found in terms of $m$ and $n$ but I don't know how to find the angle required. Is this a sensible approach, if so, how do I find the angle that I need for scalar product? If no, how should I prove it?

Answer (score 0):

By the Triangle Law, we get that 
$$\vec {AC} = \vec {AB} + \vec {BC}$$
$$\vec {DE} = \vec {DC} + \vec {CE}$$

So $$\vec {AC} \cdot \vec {DE} = (\vec {AB} + \vec {BC}) \cdot (\vec {DC} + \vec {CE})$$
$$= \vec {AB}  \cdot \vec {DC} + \vec {BC}  \cdot \vec {DC} + \vec {AB}  \cdot \vec {CE} + \vec {BC}  \cdot \vec {CE}$$
$$= m\cdot 2m \cdot \cos 0 + |\vec {BC}|\cdot|\vec {DC}|\cdot \cos C + |\vec {AB}|\cdot|\vec {CE}|\cdot \cos C + \frac{2}{3}|\vec {BC}|^2$$

See if this helps.

Comment: Not really, I understand the steps but I still have no idea how to get rid of the cos(C) cosines - I thought about using the cosine rule but it looks like it will lead me to nowhere. How should I complete the proof?

Comment: I have successfully written that last $\frac{2}{3} |\mathbf {BC}|^2$ in terms of $n$ and $m$. Still no clue how I should go about eliminating the cosine.

Answer (score 0):

Assume AB=m vector=> DC=2m
AD = n vector

$Ac = 2m+n$
$CE= 2/3(CB)$
$CE= 2/3(-m-n)$
$De= DC+CE$
$De= 2m + 2/3(-m-n)$
$De= 4/3m -2/3n$

3Ac.de = 3(2m+n)(4/3m -2/3n)=8m2 -2n2
=expand you will see m.n vectors cancel out and you will have no problem with any cosines